# Unorderable types error when using map function

Tags: python, recursion, binary, compression

I am working on a homework problem and have a function `compress(S)` which takes a binary string. It calls another function, `count(S)` which returns the number of consecutive digits at the beginning of the string. It recursively calls `count(S)` for the entire string, and creates a list of the number of consecutive digits. For example, `compress('111000111')` would return [3, 3, 3].

Another function is then called, `reduction(n)` which takes in an `int` and returns a list in which none of the numbers are greater than a set value, `COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE`. It also alternates with 0s if the number must be split up. For example `reduction(5)` returns [2, 0, 2, 0, 1] if `COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE` is 2.

This is my code so far.

```
def count(S):
    if len(S) == 1:
        return 1
    if S[0] == S[1]:
        return 1 + count(S[1:])
    return 1

def reduction(n):
    if n <= COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE:
        return [n]
    return [COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE] + [0] + reduction(n-COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE)

def compress(S):
    if S == '':
        return []
    values = [count(S)] + compress(S[count(S):])
    red_vals = list(map(reduction, values))
    return red_vals
```

The reduction function is working but when the `compress(S)` function calls `reduction(values)` using the map function, I get an error: unorderable types: list() <= int(). The values in the values list are ints so I don't understand why I am getting this error if map is supposed to iterate through the list of ints when calling `reduction`.

Thank you!

Comment: I am using the built in map function to call 'reduction' on each int in my list 'values'. It is called in the compress function.

Comment: `map(reduction, values)` is going to return a list of the results of `reduction()` ran for each element in `values`. That means you will have a list of lists of integers. You need to flatten the result

Answer (score 2):

The error message is telling you ("unorderable types: list() <= int()"), python can't order a list and an int.  At some point `reduction()` called and `n` is  a `list` and `COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE` is an `int`.  If you can't see why or where this is happening, try putting in some print statements to see what `reduction()` is being called with and what it is returning:

```
def reduction(n):
    print(n)
    if n <= COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE:
        retval = [n]
    else:
        retval = [COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE] + [0] + reduction(n - COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE)

    print(retval)
    return retval
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a few problems.  This should fix most of them:

```
def count(S):
    if len(S) == 1:
        return 1
    if S[0] == S[1]:
        return 1 + count(S[1:])
    return 1

def reduction(n):
    if n <= COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE:
        return [n]
    return [COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE] + [0] + reduction(n-COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE)

def compress(S):
    if S == '':
        return []
    c = count(S)
    values = [c] + compress(S[c:])
    red_vals = sum(map(reduction, values), [])
    return red_vals
```